# Can't Connect to The Database in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, mysql-workbench

I was trying to connect to the database to test but am getting an error report:

> java.sql.SQLException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2847)

Can you tell me a better way to upgrade the Mysql client?

Here is my code:

```
 package DatabaseTestting;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class TestDB 
    {
         @Test
        public void ConnectToSql() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
        {
            String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/selenium";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "Admin@123";

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

             System.out.println("Driver Loaded");

             DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,user,pass);

             System.out.println("Connected to Database");


        }

    }
```

I was looking everywhere, but I can't find a solution. Please help me to sort out this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the version of the mysql-connector-java jar to latest version. Latest version for the jar is 8.0.13. You can find more details at below link
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java